# Pass Array or List of Images C#

Tags: c#

I need to know how I can pass an array or a list of Images to another class in C# (Doesn't matter which one). I can create the array or list just fine and it has my Images in them but no matter which one I try to pass I get the error "The type arguments for method "'AppLayer.SymbolSetSetup.AddSymbolSet(string, System.Collections.Generic.List)'" cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

I Get these two errors when I run it "error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'AppLayer.SymbolSetSetup.AddSymbolSet(string, System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments" and "error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

Don't know if it matters but its in passing from WPF project to C# classes project.

```
    private void saveDeckButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        AppLayer.SymbolSetSetup ss = new AppLayer.SymbolSetSetup();

        // get all images in image dock
        int count = imageWrapPanel1.Children.Count;
        Image[] imArray = new Image[count];
        List<Image> list = new List<Image>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // get image from button
            Button source = (Button)imageWrapPanel1.Children[i];
            Image content = source.Content as Image;
            imArray[i] = content;
            list.Add(content);
        }

        ss.AddSymbolSet(symbolSetNameTextBox.Text, list);
    }


public class SymbolSetSetup : ServerStartup
{
    public void AddSymbolSet(string symbolSetName, List<Image> list) 
    {...
```

Comment: cannot see a line where this kind of error might come from - maybe you can tell us in which line the compiler complains (would have helped if you hadn't discarded the methods name from the error too!)

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the full exact error message and stack  trace?

Comment: Sorry, I added the errors I get when I run it.

Comment: I tried it as an array and I get the error "error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image[]' to 'System.Drawing.Image[]'" maybe because the Image in the classes differ, one .Windows the other .Drawing

Comment: The error is on the "ss.AddSymbolSet(symbolSetNameTextBox.Text, list);" line.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, your `Image` class is different in both cases. Try using the full name (inc. the namepsace) in your `AddSymbolSet` method.

```
public void AddSymbolSet(string symbolSetName, List<System.Windows.Controls.Image> list)
```

Comment: Tried that but I can't add the reference for System.Windows.Controls.Image

Comment: Is SymbolSetSetup located in a different assembly? If so, you will need to go to that assembly's project, right click, add references, and choose PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Thanks Shahar, I had to add PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, WindowsBase, and Windows.Xaml reference to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says that system cant understand what kind of image do you pass:System.Windows.Controls.Image or System.Drawing.Image. Try to organize usings.